# Inserir data event numa table se width da página for menor que determinado valor

Tags: javascript, html

O que quero fazer é que quando a `width` da página for menor do que o valor em baixo mostrado ele insira  `data-tablesaw-mode="stack` no sítio mostrado em baixo! Sou novo no `JavaScript` mas preciso disto para um projeto! Obrigado a quem ajudar estou disponível a fornecer qualquer informação que seja importante.

**O que pretendo inserir**

```
 data-tablesaw-mode="stack"
```

**Como estou tentando fazer**

```
<script>
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
var table = document.getElementsById('table-hide');

if width<39.9375em {
   table. += "data-tablesaw-mode="stack";
}
</script>
```

**HTML onde pretendo inserir**

```
<table id="table-hide" class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack">
```

Comment: Está aberto para usar Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para funcionar conforme desejado, você deve colocar o documento para escutar o evento [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/resize), crie uma função:

```
function screen_width() {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    if(width < 400) {
        // Adiciona o atributo
        tabela.setAttribute('data-tablesaw-mode', 'stack');
    } else {
        // Remove o atributo
        tabela.removeAttribute('data-tablesaw-mode');
    }
}
```

depois coloque o documento para escutar o evento:

```
// Escuta o evento
window.addEventListener('resize', screen_width);
```

chame a função para verificar quando a página é carregada.

```
// Executa a primeira vez
screen_width();
```

#### Código completo:

```
var tabela = document.getElementById('table-hide');

function screen_width() {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    if(width < 400) {
        // Adiciona o atributo
        tabela.setAttribute('data-tablesaw-mode', 'stack');
    } else {
        // Remove o atributo
        tabela.removeAttribute('data-tablesaw-mode');
    }
}

// Escuta o evento
window.addEventListener('resize', screen_width);

// Executa a primeira vez
screen_width();
```

#### Referências:

- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/resize)
- [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
- [Element.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Comment: Certo amigo muito obrigado! O único problema é que agora está inserindo e tirando mas não está fazendo o que devia fazer quando têm esse data-tablesawmode vou tentar resolver já me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Creio que se estive utilizando algum script, devera chamar ele novamente.

Comment: Já percebi meu erro, os scritps do jquery estava obstruindo o plugin que estou a utilizar! Funcionando na perfeição!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer assim

```
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth; 

if(width < 39.9375){ //Valor em pixeis
   document.getElementById('table-hide').setAttribute("data-tablesaw-mode", "stack");
}
```

Comment: Amigo não parece estar funcionado! Pelo menos não está inserido e já converti os em em pixeis!

Comment: Ponha isto e diga o que devolve `alert(width)`

Comment: Devolve corretamente o valor de width atual! Testei em 3 tamanhos de página diferentes!

Comment: Eu tinha escrito `getElementsById` e tem de ser `getElementById`, tente agora

Comment: Resultado é o mesmo que antes não está inserindo no sítio!

Comment: Eu fiz um teste no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vynckrjm/2/) e deu corretamente

Comment: Estou inserindo igual ao que meteu e nada

Comment: Algum erro na consola?

Comment: Não, não mostra nada!

Comment: Vou dar um ponto a você pela tentativa de ajuda só faltava o que o amigo deu em baixo!